# Camera API (Detect good pictures, rule of thirds etc)

Tags: api, camera, webcam

So I am working on an app that will be taking pictures. I am using OpenCV to do things like detect that people are present in the picture. However what I would like to be able to do is detect if the picture is "good".

I am not sure exactly how to approach it but some ideas are:

- I want to either detect a picture follows the rule of thirds. If it does not it could adjust the camera.
- Have different types of pictures. So sometimes take a picture of a group and other times individual shots.

I think it may be easiest to take the picture and then try and crop it to meet one of these requirements? But I was wondering if there is any api or something that would be helpful for this?